# How to make something be painted only when certain parameters are met?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make virtual monopoly just for kicks and I'm trying to have the property card displayed whenever the player is on the property.

The problem is I can't figure out how to make the image be painted when a certain value is met.

Here is my code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (method.meditaranean_land == 1)
    {
        properties = "C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Pictures\\properties\\medditeraneans_good.jpg";
    }
    if (method.baltic_land == 1)
    {
        properties = "C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Pictures\\properties\\baltic_good.jpg";
    }
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(properties);
    icon.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 300);

    public void checkLand()
    {
        //checks which property the player is on
        if (location == 1)
        {
            meditaranean_land=1;
        }
        if (location == 2)
        {
            community_land=1;
        }
        if (location == 3)
        {
            baltic_land=1;
        }
        if (location == 4)

        // And so on...
```

All that I need to know is how to make say meditaranean be painted when `Mediterranean_land = 1`.

```
action_screen action = new action_screen();

public static void main(String[]args) {
    Board_Game board = new Board_Game();
    board.graphics();
    board.gameplay();  
}

public void graphics()
{
    gui.beans();
    action.displayButtons(); 
}

public void gameplay()
{
    Methods method = new Methods();
    method.checkLocation();
    method.checkLand();
}
}
```

Comment: Use if-statements like `if (Mediterranean_land = 1) { // Paint it...}`. Or is your question rather how to paint it in the first place?

Comment: Your code shows a lot of hard coding, and your question is somewhat XY Problemish, suggesting that you probably want to do more "abstraction", more separating the logic out of the GUI. If this were my project, I'd try to structure the program in a Model-View-Controller (MVC) structure.

Comment: I'm more asking if there is a way to edit when the painting happens. Because as it is right now it will paint if i change the value manually but because it paints before checking the location it doesn't do it automatically. I cant move when the Jframe is initialised because it needs to be visible.

Comment: When painting will happen is not fully in your control. You can suggest that it happen by calling `repaint()`, but that is not a guarantee that it will paint. And sometimes the operating system will instigate a repaint, completely out of your control. What you can control is what is painted when painting occurs, and for that you could use the logic given by @Zabuza. But again, you seem to be hard coding a lot of what gets done within the paintComponent method -- don't do that. You also seem to be reading in files from within paintComponent -- **NEVER** do that. This method must be fast.

Comment: Best to simply swap ImageIcons in a JLabel when the state of your program changes. But we can go on and on discussing generalities, if you have a specific question about your code and your problem, you're going to want to create and post a valid [mcve] -- a very small program that compiles and runs and shows your problem directly for us, one that uses images found publicly online so that we can use those images too.